# How do you rank holiday importance in a Facebook prophet model?

Tags: machine-learning, python, time-series

I am using both the built-in holidays calendar as well as some additional holidays like marketing events in my prophet prediction. Using plot_components I am able to see the effect that holidays as a whole are having, but I am wondering if there is a way to see which holidays have the largest effect.